# Gerar Classe a Partir XSD - CTE para Webservice SEFAZ

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, xsd

Referente a geração de classes NFE e CTE a partir do XSD para utilização nos Webservices do SEFAZ.

Tenho tido alguns problemas de ambiguidade no nome das classes geradas.
Utilizei a ferramenta do Visual Studio Tools para gerar a classe a partir do XSD.

No entanto quando importo uma segunda .cs gerada para a solution ( mesmo que em projeto diferente ) ele acusa diversas ambiguidades entre as classes.
Como posso corrigir isso sem afetar o schema final na geração do xml?

Comment: Esta linha de comando pode ser usada para gerar as Classes, tendo os Schemas da NF-e: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/218780/5704

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o xsd.exe está gerando classes cujo nomes estão em conflito com outras classes do seu projeto, você pode especificar um `namespace` diferente quando chamá-la:

```
xsd.exe /namespace:Meu.Novo.Namespace <outros parametros>
```

Um projeto pode ter classes com o mesmo nome, contanto que estejam em namespaces diferentes.

Comment: Obrigado @carlosfigueira consegui resolver facilmente com esse comando era isso mesmo o problema.