# Como Ler e Converter arquivo de extensão .xsd para uma classe C#

Tags: c#, .net, nfe

Como Ler e Converter  arquivo de extensão .xsd  para uma classe C# o intuito disso e converter os schema do site sefaz para pode gerar um xml com esquema correto para poder emitir NFE.

Comment: isso é chato p caramba...rsrs você quer gerar as classes em C# a partir dos schemas ? é isso ?

Comment: se tiver outra maneira de pegar aquele schema ali e converter para ficar sempre igual seria bom

Comment: Veja essa minha resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44245/5846

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta linha de comando pode ser usada para gerar as Classes, tendo os Schemas da NF-e:

```
xsd.exe nfe_v3.10.xsd xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01.xsd /c /edb
```

Observe que é preciso incluir o nome de todos os XSDs importados no no schema principal, por isto o **nfe_v3.10** e **xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01**

O XSD fica acessível ao utilizar o Prompt de Comando do Visual Studio.
[image: Acessando]
[image: Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017]

Comment: converti gerei schema fiz assinatura mais ainda estou com erro falha no schema  se tiver algum schema  xml para versão nova de NfeDistribuição para compartilhar

Comment: Eu estava procurando hoje o Schema oficial da nova versão de NfeDistribuição, mas também não encontrei. Se você encontrar, por favor, me diz.

Comment: Encontrei: https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=n3Kn9%20YZNak=

Comment: O zip dos [esquemas que baixei](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/listaConteudo.aspx?tipoConteudo=/fwLvLUSmU8=) possui 20 arquivos xsd. Devo gerar minha classe a partir de todos eles? Se não for, quais são os corretos? E como saber a order certa? Quando executo o comando para gerar a classe a partir de todos os XSD, ele tenta criar um arquivo cujo nome é o nome de todos os arquivos concatenados, então ele dá um erro, que o nome do arquivo é grande demais para ser gerado.

Comment: Tente com este arquivo: http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=BALgvpK9Jvo=   Esquemas XML NF-e - Pacote de Liberação No. 9 (Novo leiaute da NF-e, NT 2016.002 v.1.40) (24/10/2017) (ZIP)

Comment: xsd.exe nfe_v4.00.xsd xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01.xsd /c /edb

Answer (score 3):

Eu utilizei o https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/ um addon pro visual studio. Depois de instalado, basta clicar com botão direito no xsd (dentro do solution explorer) e depois em `Run Xsd2Code Generation`.

Comment: funciona apenas na versão do visual studio 2010 e 2013