# C# - Manutenção de Classes geradas a partir de arquivo xsd

Tags: c#, xsd

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que utiliza classes geradas a partir de arquivos xsd disponibilizados pela receita federal com o **xsd.exe**. Utilizo-as para serializar arquivos xml a partir dos objetos destas classes após realizar validação do que foi preenchido com o próprio xsd.

Até aí tudo bem, o problema é que estes arquivos xsd mudam de versão quando a receita federal bem entende, o que vai me causar muita dor de cabeça pra atualizar o xsd e a classe gerada a partir dele para todos os clientes.

Me forçaria a gerar novamente a classe C# a partir do xsd de nova versão e recompilar a aplicação. O que é muito ruim. Sem falar que se eu comer bola e algum cliente ficar sem a build a atualizada, nenhum xml gerado pela aplicação será válido.

Ok chega de choro, como sou muito amador, gostaria de perguntar:
Existe uma forma de manter os arquivos xsd e suas respectivas classes atualizadas sem tanto trabalho manual?

Comment: Pode adicionar duas versoes diferentes do ficheiro xsd á sua pergunta para ter um contexto melhor do problema?

Comment: @BrunoCosta acredito que o colega não está mais acompanhando a comunidade, mas, me parece uma pergunta ainda pertinente. Os XSD a que se refere são da documentação da nota fiscal eletronica, que podem ser encontrados aqui: http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/listaConteudo.aspx?tipoConteudo=/fwLvLUSmU8= (várias versões inclusive)

Comment: O problema é que se o XSD muda radicalmente, é porque as coisas foram mudadas por quem fez o esquema, o governo, infelizmente. Quando a mudança é incremental, menos o código a ser mudado.

Answer (score 1):

A classe C# gerada é a representação do Esquema usado, no caso descrito a partir do arquivo XSD (Definição de Esquema XML), portanto é lógico que se o esquema original muda, a classe deve mudar de acordo. **O ideal é não editar esta classe gerada pelo XSD.exe. Quando houver alterações, deve-se gerar novas classes usando a ferramente XSD.exe, adequar o código do programa, compilar e distribuir a nova versão.**

De fato:

1) O problema é que se o XSD muda radicalmente, é porque as coisas foram mudadas por quem fez o esquema, o governo, infelizmente o código também tem que ser alterado.
Quando a mudança é incremental, menos o código a ser mudado.

Acho que no momento não é possível ter uma solução completamente automática para atualizar o codigo/lógica do aplicativo + dados do banco de dados conforme os esquemas do XSD do governo mudam.

Então por enquanto o que se pode fazer é quando houver alterações nos layouts / XSD, rodar novamente o XSD.exe criando as novas classes atualizadas, e adequar o código e lógica que utiliza estas classes.

2) Para manter o aplicativo atualizado no cliente você pode usar o [ClickOnce com WPF](https://www.bing.com/search?q=WPF%20ClickOnce), o [.appinstaller](https://www.bing.com/search?q=UWP%20AppInstaller) ou [MSIX (preview)](https://www.bing.com/search?q=UWP%20MSIX) com UWP.

Estas tecnologias podem ser configuradas para verificar se há nova versão do Aplicativo e então fazer o download e atualizar no cliente.
[image: ClickOnce]

Comment: Ver também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217909/5704